# Combining two csv files content line by line in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, multiple-columns, file-handling

I am working on two csv files in python.I have to combine the contents of these two csv files in such a way that the columns of both the file will be combined.

### file1.csv

```
john,willy,wight
clark,ricky,martin
shane,gilly,rocky
```

### file2.csv

```
1
2
3
```

My output file will look like :

### output.csv

```
john,willy,wight,1
clark,ricky,martin,2
shane,gilly,rocky,3
```

---

Initially i have tried some code that i have written below here:

```
myfile1 = open("file1.csv","r")
myfile2 = open("file2.csv","r")
myfile3 = open("file3.csv","w")

`for i in myfile1:
    for j in myfile2:
        myfile3.write(i + j)
myfile3.close()
myfile2.close()
myfile1.close()
```

The output i am getting is :

```
a,b,c
1
a,b,c
2
a,b,c
3
a,b,c
4
a,b,c
5
a,b,c
6
a,b,c
7
```

This is all i have tried.Help me to resolve this issue.Thankx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your line in the nested loop to `myfile3.write(i.replace("\n", "") + j)`.

The problem in your code is that, when you read in `i` and `j`, they both have a newline character at the end. To fix this, I've replaced the newline character in `i` to `""` so that there is only one newline character being written.

By the way, the following code is neater:

```
with open("file1.csv", "r") as myfile1 and open("file2.csv", "r") as myfile2 and open("file3.csv", "w"):
    for i in myfile1 and j in myfile2:
        myfile3.write(i.replace("\n", "") + j)
```

Comment: Adi C,thank you for the quick response.So the \n at both the end of files were creating the problem ,now after replacing one by null it is working fine.

Comment: @user7515829 Spot on! Please could you accept if it works for you as this will help people in the future who encounter your problem.